# preg_split : including empty field

Tags: php, string, preg-split

I want to split a TSV string. The structure is:

```
 abc\tdef\tghi\tjklm
```

where \t is a tab character.

If I use preg_split to split such string $i

```
 $field=preg_split("/\t/", $i);
```

$field[3] is jklm.

However, if I have another string

```
abc\tdef\t\t
```

$field[3] is not a valid index.

How can I force empty fields into $field, such that all $field arrays would have an equal number of indexes?

Comment: This should be the normal behaviour. Your example gives me an array back with 4 elements where 2 and 3 are empty strings. According to doc http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php there is a flag called PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY which must not be set if you want back empty elements.

Comment: Why even use preg split? It's not a regex problem `\t` is static so why use regex?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem just for extracting **Tab Separator Value** data, you can use built 
in php function (`fgetcsv()`). It is more stable than use our own function. Please try this

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // extract csv using tab delimiter
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
        print_r($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$str ="abc\tdef\t\t";

Var_dump(explode("\t", $str));
```

https://3v4l.org/7qOPJ